# FileTransform@1 task not working as expected

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using yaml FileTransform@1 to transform my file but its not working. it simply skips updating the file

tried using xmlTransformationRules and declaring filetype and tragetfiles but nothing seems to work

```
    - task: FileTransform@1
      inputs:
        folderPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/**/${{ parameters.projectToDeploy }}.zip'         
        enableXmlTransform: true
        xmlTransformationRules: '-transform **\MyConfig.Dev.config -xml **\MyConfig.config -result **\MyConfig.config'
```

MyConnfig.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<authenticationConfig xmlns:config="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration" xmlns:type="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration:type" config:version="11.1.6800.0">
    <securityTokenServiceSettings>
        <identityServerSettings enableLogging="True" mapUsersViaEmail="True" />
        <authenticationProviders>
                <add somecustomvalue ="1">
        </authenticationProviders>
    </securityTokenServiceSettings>
</authenticationConfig>
```

MyConfig.Dev.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<authenticationConfig xmlns:config="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration" xmlns:type="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration:type" config:version="11.0.6700.0"  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <securityTokenServiceSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <identityServerSettings enableLogging="True" mapUsersViaEmail="True" />
    <authenticationProviders >
      <add mynewvalue="2"/>
    </authenticationProviders>
  </securityTokenServiceSettings>
</authenticationConfig>
```

new error i am getting is

```
2019-09-30T23:49:01.0338926Z ##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key:FailedToApplySpecialTransformation 
2019-09-30T23:49:01.0348290Z ##[warning]FailedToApplySpecialTransformation
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue caused by your incorrect written for your config file name. You should change the `xmlTransformationRules` value as `'-transform **\MyConfig.Dev.config -xml **\MyConnfig.config -result **\MyConfig.config'`. Because you defined the source xml file name as `MyConnfig.config`.

Refer to this [FileTransform task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/FileTransformV1/filetransform.ts#L22) source code. It's actual apply script is [apply transform](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/93875bcafce5efd3ed0c89e98bd28f880268ed67/Tasks/Common/webdeployment-common/xdttransformationutility.ts#L83). You can see the error message you received is because the `isTransformationApplied` is `false`, and since the file names do not match with each other, then the `for` loop could not be executed.

[image]

The error message means sorry, I don’t think the file you provided is match with the one that rule mentioned, so I could not help you apply this transform process.

---

The first issue would be solved, but now, in your `MyConfig.Dev.Config` file, it seems be a  invalid xml. Because I tested your config files, and receive the error message:

```
The 'add' start tag on line 6 position 18 does not match the end tag of 'authenticationProviders'
```

In your MyConnfig.config file, you lose `/` in the tag `<add>`

Comment: Spell error was just on this stackoverflow. My config file is not named MyConnfig.config it is named MyConfig.config

Comment: @ThinkaraKara,Not yet, as I test, if the file name is not same with the name in `xmlTransformationRules`, it will cause this error. You can see the source code I mentioned in my answer. If the names not match each other, the for loop would not be executed and run If loop directly. Its message is what you received in log.

Comment: @ThinkaraKara, not sure what's exactly definition name in your repos. But, you must ensure that the name in `xmlTransformationRules` is same with your file name. Because the compile message should not be like this you ever received.